# How can a character a and string a stored differently except than a null termination in c?

Tags: c, string, memory, char

I came across this line from a book it was written when we store "a" as a string its stored as a character constant followed by null character and a pointer points to it. But when we store a character 'a' it's stored as a integer in memory. 
Is not the string is also stored as a corresponding integer only to be terminated by a null character.

Comment: Every single character of string is stored in the similar way how a character is stored. i.e. its integer value from character set (like, ASCII) is stored. If you traverse through a string and print using '%d' format specifier instead of '%c' you'll see the same. Strings should have a starting address and end. We get starting address of this chunk of memory by using pointer and know that we have reached the end when we encounter null character, while a character 'a' is only a single piece of memory, we know it's length is not more than 1 so we don't need null character.

Comment: ASCII strings are stored as a sequence of Bytes (8-bit code) not integers (2-byte, 4-byte, 8-byte depending on size).  "Hello to you" is stored as 13 bytes (12 letters + \0).  It will not fit in an integer.

Comment: @DaveS now i got what the author was talking about. Thanks.

Comment: "when we store "a" as a string its stored as a character constant followed by null character and a pointer points to it." --> "when we store "a" as a string its stored as a character constant followed by null character". A _pointer_ is not needed to form a _string_.  e.g. `a[] = "Hello";`.

Comment: @DaveS: `char` values are integers. “Integer” does not mean the `int` type.

Comment: @EricPostpischil yes, but I wanted to make clear it was not in fact an int type, the poster seemed to think it might be,

Answer (score 0):

A string is a sequence of character values including a 0-valued terminator - the string `"hello"` is represented by the character sequence `{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0}`.

Each individual character is represented as a small integer, which stores the encoding for that character (ASCII, EBCDIC, UTF-8, or some other encoding).  The ASCII encoding for the above sequence would be `{104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 0}`.

Strings are stored in arrays of character type (`char` for ASCII, EBCDIC, and UTF-8, `wchar_t` for “wide” character encodings like UTF-16).  This includes string literals, which are stored such that they are visible over the entire program.

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" is converted ("decays") to type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression is the address of the first element of the array.  That’s why you see `char *` so often when dealing with strings - that’s a consequence of how C treats array expressions.

Most string and I/O library functions take a `char *` argument, which points to the first character in the string (that is, the first element of the array that stores the string).  Those functions will process those strings by “walking” through the array until they see that 0 terminator.  Since all that gets passed to the function is the address of the first element, the function has no idea how big the array storing the function is.  It relies on the presence of that 0 terminator to know when to stop processing. That’s why operations like `strcpy` can be dangerous - if you try to copy a 20 character string to an array that’s only sized to hold 10 characters, those extra 10 characters will be written to the memory following the array, which will have unpredictable effects.